# How to make first 2 tabs of radtabstrip mandatory to be filled out?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have an ASP.NET project with telerik embedded. 
The telerik control I have is RadTabStrip.
The current task  is The customer wants the first 2 tabs "Employee" and "general info" to be fill out first before they are able to fill out the other tabs.

Not sure how to implement this. Here is a sample

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1"
            Skin="Telerik" CausesValidation="false">
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Selected="True">
                    <TabTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, sample_generalinformation %>" />
                        <img id="generalInfoErrorIndicator" src="../Images/alert-small.gif" alt="" style="display: none;" />
                    </TabTemplate>
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server">
```

Here is the tab code.

```
<!-- EMPLOYEE INFORMATION -->
            <telerik:RadPageView ID="pvEmployeeInformation" runat="server">
                <div id="employeeInfoDiv" runat="server">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <h1>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label34" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, observed_employee_information %>" /></h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, employee_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:EmployeeSearch ID="employeeSearch" runat="server" OnClientEmployeeSelected="employeeSelected"
                                    ClientValidationFunction="validateEmployee" ValidationGroup="employeeInfo" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="areaSampleCheckBox" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, labels_areasample %>"
                                                ValidationGroup="employeeInfo" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="unknownEmployeeCheckBox" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, labels_unknownemployee %>"
                                                ValidationGroup="employeeInfo" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, job_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:JobSearch ID="jobSearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="employeeInfo" ClientValidationFunction="validateJob"
                                    OnClientJobSelected="jobSelected" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="unknownJobCheckBox" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, labels_unknownjob %>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, shift_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:NewShiftDropDown ID="shiftDropDown" runat="server" ValidationGroup="employeeInfo" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, shiftlength_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:NewShiftLengthDropDown ID="shiftLengthDropDown" runat="server" ValidationGroup="employeeInfo" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="employeeInformationValidationSummary" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"
                                    ForeColor="Red" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:strings, validationsummary_nextwizard_msg %>"
                                    ValidationGroup="employeeInfo" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </telerik:RadPageView>
```

And another

```
<!-- GENERAL INFORMATION -->
            <telerik:RadPageView ID="pvGeneralInformation" runat="server">
                <div id="generalInfoDiv" runat="server">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <h1>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, general_information %>" /></h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, facility_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:FacilitySearch ID="facilitySearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="generalInfo"
                                    OnClientFacilitySelected="facilitySelected" OnClientFacilityCleared="facilityCleared"
                                    AutoPostBack="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, samplelength_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:NewSampleLengthDropDown ID="sampleLengthDropDown" runat="server" ValidationGroup="generalInfo" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, sampledate_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:NewDateEntry ID="sampleDate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="generalInfo"
                                    ValidateDateNotInFuture="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, samplemethod_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:SampleMethodSearch ID="sampleMethodSearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="generalInfo"
                                    OnClientSampleMethodSelected="sampleMethodSelected" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, sampletype_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:NewSampleTypeDropDown ID="sampleTypeDropDown" runat="server" ValidationGroup="generalInfo"
                                    FormDesignator="PassiveBadge" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label69" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, samplenumber_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="sampleNumberTextBox" runat="server" Skin="Telerik" Width="200px" />&nbsp;<asp:Image
                                    ID="sampleNumberInfoImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/info.png" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:strings, samplenumber_info %>" />
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator19" runat="server"
                                    ControlToValidate="sampleNumberTextBox" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:strings, validations_fieldlength_16 %>"
                                    ToolTip="<%$ Resources:strings, validations_fieldlength_16 %>" ValidationExpression="<%$ AppSettings:Length16ValidationExpression %>"
                                    ValidationGroup="generalInfo" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, occupationalhealthlimit_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:OelSearch ID="oelSearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="generalInfo" OnClientOelSelected="oelSelected" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, labsamplenumber_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="labSampleNumberTextBox" runat="server" Skin="Telerik" Width="175px" />
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="labSampleNumberTextBox"
                                    ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:strings, labsamplenumber_length %>" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:strings, labsamplenumber_length %>"
                                    ValidationExpression="<%$ AppSettings:Length64ValidationExpression %>" ValidationGroup="generalInfo" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label67" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, exposuregroup_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:ExposureGroupSearch ID="exposureGroupSearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="generalInfo" />
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, stelsample_label %>"
                                                Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="stelSampleCheckBox" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label68" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, labels_ceiling %>"
                                                Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="ceilingSampleCheckBox" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, collectinguser_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:AdminUserSearch ID="adminUserSearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="generalInfo" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, samplingdevice_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:NewSamplingDeviceDropDown ID="samplingDeviceDropDown" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, samplestrategy_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <ihamm:NewSampleStrategyDropDown ID="sampleStrategyDropDown" runat="server" ValidationGroup="generalInfo" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, blanknumber_label %>"
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="blankNumberTextBox" runat="server" Skin="Telerik" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="blankNumberTextBox"
                                    ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:strings, blanknumber_required %>" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:strings, blanknumber_required %>"
                                    ValidationGroup="generalInfo" />
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="blankNumberTextBox"
                                    ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:strings, blanknumber_length %>" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:strings, blanknumber_length %>"
                                    ValidationExpression="<%$ AppSettings:Length64ValidationExpression %>" ValidationGroup="generalInfo" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="generalInformationValidationSummary" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"
                                    ForeColor="Red" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:strings, validationsummary_nextwizard_msg %>"
                                    ValidationGroup="generalInfo" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </telerik:RadPageView>
```

Comment: Which controls do you have in those two RadTabStrips you like to be filled in first?

Comment: @FeliceM I see RadpageView for TELERIK and Labels,validation summary,checkbox for ASP. I also see employeesearch for a custom made thing it's neither ASP or telerik.

Comment: In your code above there is nothing in the RadTabStrip that needs to be completed. I assume you would like to place textboxes inside the TabTemplate and only once all of them are completed then make visible or editable the other RadStripTabs. If so you can use validators or in code behind access those textboxes and craft the conditions. Post your code with the controls if you need more help.

Comment: @FeliceM I have posted the tab code. Any help is greatly appreciated.This is the proposed mandatory tab but the rest of the tabs are of similar fashion.

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: @FeliceM hi, Yes and No. Yes the code implementation that you provided was extremely helpful but the customer changed up the requirements on me ( typical ). But really I EXTREMELY appreciate you assisting as much as you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to give you a solution based on your own code because of all the custom references. However, the controls in the various tabs can be accessed directly from code behind. I made a test on a 3 tabs RadTabStrip playing on enabling tab2.

**UPDATE**

Something went wrong with the previous example. I had to use some Javascript to resolve the issue on the client side. I tested this code and it is working. Basically there are two textboxes on the first tab and a button that is disabled by default. The button gets enabled only if text is in both textboxes (I understood you have more than one control on the tab that needs to be filled-in so this is a good example). Then clicking the button you enable tab 2. You can rewrite the javascript to enable directly the tabs when your fields/controls on the first and second tab are satisfying the requirements.

In PAGE_LOAD set the tabs that should not be visible or enabled

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //RadTabStrip1.Tabs[2].Visible = false;
    RadTabStrip1.Tabs[2].Enabled = false;
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadTabStrip1.Tabs[2].Enabled = true;
    }
```

Here is the rest of the code with the script

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        //function to enable button if two textboxes contains text
        function SetButtonStatus(sender, target) {
            var first = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>');
            var second = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>');
            //Condition to check whether user enters text in two textboxes or not
            if ((sender.value.length >= 1 && first.value.length >= 1) && (sender.value.length >= 1 && second.value.length >= 1))
                document.getElementById(target).disabled = false;
            else
                document.getElementById(target).disabled = true;
        }
    </script>


    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
    <div>
        <telerik:RadTabStrip RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip1" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0" Skin="Silk">
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="I am Tab 0" Width="200px"></telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="I am Tab 1" Width="200px"></telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="I am Tab 2" Width="200px"></telerik:RadTab>
            </Tabs>
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
        <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="outerMultiPage">
            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView1">
                <telerik:RadTabStrip RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip2" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage2"
                    Orientation="VerticalLeft" Skin="Silk" Width="50px" Height="355px" SelectedIndex="0">
                </telerik:RadTabStrip>
                <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPage2" SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="innerMultiPage">
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="PageView1">
                        <div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this,'btnButton')"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this,'btnButton')"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                        </div>
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                </telerik:RadMultiPage>
            </telerik:RadPageView>
            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView2">
                <div></div>
                <div>
                    <p>Something</p>
                </div>
            </telerik:RadPageView>
            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView3">
                <div>
                    <p>Again something</p>
                </div>
            </telerik:RadPageView>
        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out to write all this out.  I am unsure why my "RadTabStrip1.Tabs[2].Visible = false;" does not work for me  .enabled does not work either . Any thoughts on why? I am sure its a minor thing I am overlooking.

Comment: Where are you placing it? Tab index starts from 0. Let me know

Comment: yes I am adding it to the top of the page_load function in the .cs file.  I tried both .visible and .enable and used 2-7

Comment: @TDang I have updated  my answer. It is now working properly.